# Using SQLite with Rubymotion

Tags: sqlite, rubymotion

I want to use the C-level SQLite API with Rubymotion, but I'm not sure how to include the SQLite dylib & header files, if it is possible at all.

As I understand the dylib should be included in the following way:

```
app.libs += ['/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib']
```

But that's not enough, the `sqlite3_open` function is still not found. I guess the header file should be specified somehow.

P.S. I know that I can use FMDB to get the same functionality, but I'm wondering about using the C library directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not having any issues with mine. Here's my lib entry:

```
app.libs += ['/usr/lib/libz.dylib', '/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib']
```

Maybe you need the libz.dylib part.

Comment: Thanks Jamon, so when you run something like `sqlite3_open(nil, nil)` in the Rubymotion console, you are not getting an undefined method error, right?

Comment: Hm, just tried it and got undefined. A library I'm using needs the sqlite3 library but I'm not actually using it in code. Sorry about that. The library dies without the above libs and works fine with them included. Not sure why it's not available in code or the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out https://github.com/sxross/MotionModel/tree/sql. I've built an ActiveRecord-like adapter for SQLite using FMDB. The sample app might be a good reference for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [fmdb cocoapod github repository](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) currently (as of Feb 26 2014) has 3970 favorites on github, 918 forks, and 336 watchers.

I think this is what you are looking for. fmdb is an Objective C wrapper on top of sqlite.

To get started with cocoapods, run:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

the ruby motion gem for handling cocoapods is `motion-cocoapods`

I'm still looking for an activerecord-like ORM though. there's the `motion-sqlite3` gem but so far I haven't been able to get it to work. (5 minutes later) though the `motion-model` gem is looking promising...& heavily documented

Answer (score 0):

By the way, it's 2020 now and you can easily work with SQLite in a RubyMotion iOS app by using the [`motion-sqlite3`](https://github.com/mattgreen/motion-sqlite3) gem. It hasn't been updated in a while, but that's because it just works.